# Android locationmanager not calling methods

Tags: android, gps

I'm having trouble with the locationmanager in Android. I have the following class:

```
package com.flyer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ContentProvider implements LocationListener {
    private Activity connectedActivity;

    public ContentProvider(Activity connectedActivity) {
        this.connectedActivity = connectedActivity;
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)connectedActivity.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 100, 0, this);
    }

    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)
    {
        MyActivity.rowsData.add(new RowData(0, "Test", "Val: " + Math.random(), 0));
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
    {
        Intent in = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
        connectedActivity.startActivity(in);
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
    {
        Toast.makeText(connectedActivity.getApplicationContext(),
                "Gps Enabled",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
    {
        MyActivity.rowsData.add(new RowData(0, "Test", "Val: "+Math.random(), 0));
    }


}
```

I call the constructor ContentProvider(this) in my mainactivity. However when I telnet to my emulator and do a geo fix, nothing happens.

I tried setting the content with a breakpoint, it won't reach.

Also I'm developing for Android 2.1.

Any help would be appreciated.

Getting a warning:

```
10-30 21:10:38.787: WARN/GpsLocationProvider(52): Could not open GPS configuration file /etc/gps.conf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you publish your manifest XML?  Have you added the permissions necessary?

```
<android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" /> 
<android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Were you getting any exceptions in your logcat trace?  I recommend trying this on a real device to rule out config issues with your emulator.

FYI, here's how I turn on debug trace for my app using `adb logcat`:

```
adb shell stop
adb shell setprop log.tag.MYTAG DEBUG
adb shell start
adb logcat MYTAG:D *:W > c:\temp\trace.txt
```

To avoid having to mess around with DEBUG level trace, I suggest you stick with logging at Log.INFO level.  In that case you only need the last command.

Comment: I added the permissions, yes. I do get a warning, add in OP. Furter, I can't find any, related, errors.

Comment: Doing a Google search for that error shows that you need to set up the location in your emulator, here's how: http://groups.google.com/group/android-framework/msg/f94e0bbb227c03c6  Test with a real phone and you won't have a problem...

Comment: I tested on two phones, and get to onProviderDisabled and onProviderEnabled, but never to onLocationChanged. Somehow it's still not working properly, any ideas why?

Comment: Have you added logs to onLocationChanged, or are you assuming it isn't getting called because the rowsData.add line doesn't work?  You should probably add logs everywhere and include the logcat output in your question.

Comment: You might also find it useful to add @Override before all your overridden methods, that way Eclipse will warn you if the method is wrong for the interface you are trying to implement (in this case onLocationChanged looks okay though).

Comment: I can't momentarily use log on my phone, but rowData.add works on onProviderEnabled, so should work also on onLocationChanged. I'm using IntelliJ btw, it doesn't like unnecessary Overrides.

Comment: Thanks for your help, logcat proves that it is now working in the emu. Might have been that I forget to add GPS to the emu -_-"